# Как обратиться к экземпляру базового класса в приложении Windows Phone (c#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Добрый день!

Есть автоматически создаваемый базовый класс MainPage:

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Конструктор
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Создаю дополнительный класс **Test**, из которого хочу обращаться к методам MainPage.
Вопрос: как обратиться к экземпляру класса MainPage, заново не создавая его?

Спасибо!

Comment: сделать методы static, шо не?

Comment: Не, johniek_comp, не пойдёт, внутри этих методов нужно будет обращаться к переменным класса, которые статическими не получится сделать.

Comment: Зачем подобная изощренная на мой взгляд архитектура? Почему бы не идти от противного, чтобы форма знала про какой-то там класс Тест и она использовала его, а не наоборот? Работа приложения все равно начинается с какой-то формы, и скорей всего она создает етот загадочный тест - если уж так надо, передавайте в класс Тест ссылку на форму и дергайте из него нужные методы. Кстате в популярном для данной технологии подходе МВВМ ваш подход вообще не приемлим.

Comment: Я только недавно занялся c#, учту ваш комментарий, буду разбираться, спасибо!
Не могли бы вы привести пример, если вам не трудно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Не знаю как в винфоне, но скорее всего есть там класс типа Application и у него есть что то типа Application.MainForm - это и будет нужный экземпляр класса, его просто надо скастить к своему.
2. "Автоматически создаваемый" - это скорее всего кодом который есть в program.cs - можете там "автомат" поменять на то что надо.

Поставлю WinPhoneSDK - смогу сказать с уверенностью, но думаю по этим подсказкам найдёте нужный подход.

**UPD**

Поставил, покопался, в итоге поинтереснее всё:

1. MainPage действительно генерится аля авто в файле `WMAppManifest.xml` строчкой

   `<Tasks>
     <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
   </Tasks>`
2. Получить класс текущей страницы можно так:

   var mainPage = (((App) Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as MainPage);
3. А вот чтобы точно главная страница была - надо сохранить ссылку в классе App
   : добавим свойство

   ```
   public MainPage RootPage { get; private set; }
   ```

А в метод

```
private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
```

добавить

```
        RootPage = (RootFrame.Content as MainPage);
```

и тогда доступ будет таким:

```
var mainPage = ((App) Application.Current).RootPage;
```

Comment: Спасибо за старания, Чад!

var mainPage = (((App) Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as MainPage);

Через mainPage уже доступен весь класс MainPage, пока остановился на одной строке кода)